For How Long was the Pure Version of Christianity Around
AssalamuAlyakoom brothers and sisters. I was wondering if there any of you know how long the pure version of Christianity (the one Isa (AS) revealed) was around. I know that up until the time of Prophet Muhamad (SAW) there were still some who practiced. I mean for the amount of time that it was mainstream and practiced by many. And if any have the same information on Judaism, that would be helpful as well.
